# Question about stable manifold theorem and Frobenius integrability theorem

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, hyperbolic-dynamics

I have a question about Anosov diffeomorphism ([Wikipedia: Anosov diffeomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosov_diffeomorphism))

For hyperbolic fixed point $p$, $W^{s}(p)$ is a smooth manifold and its tangent space has the same dimension as the stable space of the linearization of $f$ at $p$.([Wikipedia: stable manifold theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_manifold_theorem))

Just recently I also heard from some talk that high dimensional Anosov diffeomorphisms (flows) the stable/unstable sub-bundles are usually not integrable. (Lie bracket is not in the those bundle). See [these lectures "Distributions and foliations" by Zuoqin Wang](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ewangzuoq/Courses/21F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec16.pdf).

I am confused that if those Anosov diffeomorphisms stable/unstable sub-bundles are not integrable but are still continuous bundles (ranging on Grassmainian manifolds),

Why stable manifolds theorem still holds so that there exist manifolds with tangent spaces spanned by the stable subspace at each points?

This is not the definition of integrable? why not contradict to each other?